# CKEditor: Text is displayed in html format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I am making a blog website in rails 5. But I wanted to create dynamic articles, where I can add headers, images and more. I discovered CKEditor. I have coded CKEditor into my form, `<%= f.cktext_area :body, ckeditor: { language: 'en', uiColor: '#F0F0F0', toolbar: 'mini'} %>` and it works great! It adds text to the body of my post, as I intended.

The only problem I have is that it is displaying in html format. The image below is a sample post I made. This is how I want my post to look after I submit.

[image]

And here is the problem. This is the exact result of the image above. When I save my post, this is what I see.

```
    <p><span style="font-size:18px">A nice header</span></p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et eam lorem assum nihil, oportere erroribus mei no. At ius errem utamur, est nonumes consectetuer necessitatibus te. Cum et sumo nulla aliquid. Eos summo nihil no. Iusto inermis no qui.</p>

    <p>Agam dicat mediocrem et vel, augue consulatu disputationi nam eu, vel id mentitum invidunt. Te assum accumsan nam, nam in recteque ullamcorper. Vix ei vitae labores legimus. Ea vis saepe meliore salutatus, usu an homero quaerendum disputationi. Eu menandri mediocritatem pri.</p>

    <hr />
    <p><img alt="" src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2016/07/23/us/politics/23fd-campaign/23fd-campaign-master768.jpg" style="height:512px; width:768px" /></p>

    <hr />
    <p>Vim minim nonumy et, quodsi pertinax at pro, eu audiam facilisi cotidieque vel. Ius no quis probatus, ad eam equidem repudiare vulputate, no eos ponderum incorrupte. Cu delenit torquatos cum, at aperiam vocibus sit. Nec euismod incorrupte et.</p>

    <p>Sit et molestie insolens oportere, dicam laudem no mel, et soleat vituperatoribus ius. In vix justo doming admodum, duo choro verear utamur an. Qui ut fugit atomorum, duo agam virtute et. Eam te nobis aliquando instructior, vix ancillae accusamus no. Nisl lucilius percipitur at pri, duo ne probo salutandi conceptam. Sed magna iudicabit forensibus ex, sed ne maiorum neglegentur.</p>

    <p>Eu vix vidit convenire, pro id lorem aliquid quaerendum. Enim lobortis no mei, labore putant delectus et qui, ad solum petentium interesset nam. Pro virtute utroque debitis et, mei eu case blandit omittantur, id sed graecis abhorreant. Sed inimicus consequat id, choro commune ad cum, per dicat laudem phaedrum te.</p>
```

How can I get CKEditor to produce posts that look like the one in the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using `<%= raw(object.body)%>`